# texmacs enter latex source code

Tags: tables, texmacs

is there in texmacs an equivalent to the Ctrl plus L shortcut in Lyx where it is possible to insert latex code to get other tables than the table environments which are doable in texmacs by default?

Comment: TeXmacs is a program that has nothing in common with TeX and friends, apart from some similarities. Questions that are specific to TeXmacs are off-topic here, sorry.